# Implication of Omnipresent

Tags: theology, reason

Omnipotent, Omniscient, Omnipresent etc. are commonly used attributes of God.  Doesn't the term 'Omnipresent' imply Non-duality also? Or at least the idea -- 'Individual soul is not different from universal soul'? If not, why?

========================================

P.S.

(summery of comments)

If the base-word 'soul' in these two terms doesn't represent the same 'aspect', why people use (or used) it for two different aspects?

Comment: Maybe both... [God is everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnipresence) but this not not necessarily mean (according to different points of view) that he **is** everything.

Comment: It does not imply it, being everywhere does not imply being exhausted by such distributed presence, let alone identical to finite souls. In the classical theism God is not just omnipresent, i.e. present in every being, but also *transcendent*, i.e. transcends all of them, is above and beyond the world with all of its souls.

Comment: @Conifold: If so, does it mean omnipresent is not present in finite souls?

Comment: Why not? Air is present in caves, but its pockets there aren't identical to the atmosphere, let alone to planet as a whole.

Comment: According to panpsychism such as Leibniz monadology, only certain types have soul such as animals, humans whose souls are created in the image of the oneness, plants have perceptions but no soul same as bare materials have no soul. In eastern philosophies and religions, usually sattva (sanskrit) are meant to have souls and thus emotions...Usually Omnipresent implies non-duality, but there's exception such as the esoteric Kabbalistic godhead...

Comment: @Conifold: That means, finite souls are never souls. If it were souls, each of them should be the absolute. In other words, **the word** used in 'soul' in finite soul and universal soul are never the same.  Again, if the two words were the same the two types of souls would be Non-dual.  Universal soul is present everywhere and is absolute and individual soul is the absolute' and they are represented by same key word, can this ever be two?

Comment: The word "soul" is used broadly to cover all kinds, so it is the same general meaning for finite and absolute souls, and this is exactly why it does not imply anything more specific. Just like the word "set" is used for finite and infinite sets with the same meaning. We add the adjectives to modify nouns exactly because the nouns do not distinguish cases by themselves. Universal soul is universal and individual soul isn't unless it is simply postulated to be, as in non-dualism.

Comment: @Conifold: But finite and infinite sets are sets. On the other hand,  either individual soul or universal soul is not a soul.

Comment: Sure they are, otherwise we'd use a different noun.

Comment: @Conifold:I was asking 'Either individual soul or universal soul is not a soul.' how is it possible?   If it were so, why people used the same word for two different 'aspects'?

Answer (score 1):

The best example that I was given of God being Omnipresent is:

Build a universe in your own mind. Build every detail to it.

What's the relationship between you and that universe? It all exists by your will. The moment you take away your will for a person to exist they cease to exist. Everyone is aware of your presence, there isn't a place/time that you're unaware of. Nor anything that anyone does in this universe affects you (the God). Like if a nuclear bomb goes off or if a fly goes to sleep or if the sun explodes, it's all the same to you as its creator.

God and its creation, both exist, but the presence of God is independent of any other being. While the presence of the creation is all dependent on God. Not that God is in a specific realm. He isn't, but just that he isn't defined/limited by place. You and I as humans are limited/scoped.

This wasn't a perfect example, but to some extent it shows what it means by saying God is present everywhere but not physically...